# OpenACC and CUDA aware MPI

Tags: gpu, mpi, openacc

I want to move on the device the whole while loop in the main. The problems emerges when I add `#pragma acc host_data use_device(err)` to `MPI_Allreduce (&err, &err, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`.

The error is that the reduction on err doesn't work so that the code exit after one step from the loop.

After the `MPI_Allreduce()`, even using `#pragma acc update self(err)`, err is still equal to zero.

I'm compiling with `mpicc -acc -ta=tesla:managed -Minfo=accel -w jacobi.c`
And running with `mpirun -np 2 -mca pml ^ucx ./a.out`

Could you help me to find the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PARALLEL
#define NX_GLOB     128   /* Global number of interior points */
#define NY_GLOB     128  /* Global number of interior points */
#define NGHOST   1
#define NDIM     2

#ifdef PARALLEL
  #include <mpi.h>
  MPI_Comm MPI_COMM_CART;
#endif

typedef struct MPI_Decomp_{
  int nprocs[NDIM];     /*  Number of processors in each dimension */
  int periods[NDIM];    /*  Periodicity flag in each dimension     */
  int coords[NDIM];     /*  Cartesian coordinate in the MPI topology */
  int gsize[NDIM];      /*  Global domain size (no ghosts)  */
  int lsize[NDIM];      /*  Local domain size (no ghosts)   */
  int start[NDIM];      /*  Local start index in each dimension           */
  int procL[NDIM];      /*  Rank of left-lying  process in each direction */
  int procR[NDIM];      /*  Rank of right-lying process in each direction */
  int rank;             /*  Local process rank */
  int size;             /*  Communicator size  */
} MPI_Decomp;



void BoundaryConditions(double **, double *, double *, int, int, MPI_Decomp *);
void DomainDecomposition(MPI_Decomp *);
void WriteSolution (double **, int, int, MPI_Decomp *);
double **Allocate_2DdblArray(int, int);
int    **Allocate_2DintArray(int, int);
void   Show_2DdblArray(double **, int, int, const char *);
void   Show_2DintArray(int **, int, int, const char *);

int nx_tot, ny_tot;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int    nx, i, ibeg, iend;
  int    ny, j, jbeg, jend;
  int    k, rank=0, size=1;
  double xbeg = 0.0, xend = 1.0;
  double ybeg = 0.0, yend = 1.0;
  double dx = (xend - xbeg)/(NX_GLOB + 1);
  double dy = (yend - ybeg)/(NY_GLOB + 1);
  double *xg, *yg, *x, *y, **phi, **phi0;
  double err, tol;
  MPI_Decomp  mpi_decomp;
  double err_glob;
  int procL[NDIM] = {-1,-1};
  int procR[NDIM] = {-1,-1};

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   0. Initialize the MPI execution environment
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

#ifdef PARALLEL
  MPI_Datatype row_type, col_type;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  DomainDecomposition(&mpi_decomp);
  nx = mpi_decomp.lsize[0];
  ny = mpi_decomp.lsize[1];
#else
  mpi_decomp.gsize[0] = mpi_decomp.lsize[0] = nx = NX_GLOB;
  mpi_decomp.gsize[1] = mpi_decomp.lsize[1] = ny = NY_GLOB;
  mpi_decomp.procL[0] = mpi_decomp.procL[1] = -1;
  mpi_decomp.procR[0] = mpi_decomp.procR[1] = -1;
#endif

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   1. Set local grid indices
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  ibeg   = NGHOST;
  iend   = ibeg + nx - 1;
  nx     = iend - ibeg + 1;
  nx_tot = nx + 2*NGHOST;

  jbeg   = NGHOST;
  jend   = jbeg + ny - 1;
  ny     = jend - jbeg + 1;
  ny_tot = ny + 2*NGHOST;

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   2. Generate global and local grids
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  xg = (double *) malloc ( (NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST)*sizeof(double));
  yg = (double *) malloc ( (NY_GLOB+2*NGHOST)*sizeof(double));
  for (i = 0; i < (NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST); i++) xg[i] = xbeg + (i-ibeg+1)*dx;
  for (j = 0; j < (NY_GLOB+2*NGHOST); j++) yg[j] = ybeg + (j-jbeg+1)*dy;
  #ifdef PARALLEL
  x = xg + mpi_decomp.start[0];
  y = yg + mpi_decomp.start[1];
  #else
  x = xg;
  y = yg;
  #endif

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   3. Allocate memory on local processor and
      assign initial conditions.
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  phi  = Allocate_2DdblArray(ny_tot, nx_tot);
  phi0 = Allocate_2DdblArray(ny_tot, nx_tot);

  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
    phi0[j][i] = 0.0;
  }}

#ifdef PARALLEL
  MPI_Type_contiguous (nx_tot, MPI_DOUBLE, &row_type);
  MPI_Type_vector     (ny_tot, 1, nx_tot, MPI_DOUBLE, &col_type);
  MPI_Type_commit (&row_type);
  MPI_Type_commit (&col_type);
#endif

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   4. Main iteration cycle
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  tol = 1.e-5;
  err = 1.0;
  k   = 0;

  #pragma acc enter data copyin(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], phi0[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], x[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], y[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], err, err_glob)
  while  (err > tol){

  /* -- 4a. Set boundary conditions first -- */

    BoundaryConditions(phi0, x, y, nx, ny, &mpi_decomp);

  /* -- 4b. Jacobi's method and residual (interior points) -- */

    err = 0.0;

    #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) reduction(+:err) present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], phi0[:ny_tot][:nx_tot])
    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
      phi[j][i] = 0.25*(  phi0[j][i-1] + phi0[j][i+1]
                        + phi0[j-1][i] + phi0[j+1][i] );

      err += dx*dy*fabs(phi[j][i] - phi0[j][i]);
    }}


    #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], phi0[:ny_tot][:nx_tot])
    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
      phi0[j][i] = phi[j][i];
    }}

    #ifdef PARALLEL
    // double err_glob;
    #pragma acc host_data use_device(err, err_glob)
    {
    MPI_Allreduce (&err, &err_glob, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    err = err_glob;
    #endif

    // #pragma acc update host(err)
    if (rank == 0){
      printf ("k = %d; err = %8.3e\n",k, err);
    }
    k++;
  }
  #pragma acc exit data copyout(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], phi0[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], err, err_glob)

  WriteSolution (phi, nx, ny, &mpi_decomp);

  #ifdef PARALLEL
  MPI_Finalize();
  #endif
  return 0;
}

#ifdef PARALLEL
/* ********************************************************************* */
void DomainDecomposition(MPI_Decomp *mpi_decomp)
/*
 *
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int dim, i;
  int rank, size;
  int *coords  = mpi_decomp->coords;
  int *gsize   = mpi_decomp->gsize;
  int *lsize   = mpi_decomp->lsize;
  int *nprocs  = mpi_decomp->nprocs;
  int *periods = mpi_decomp->periods;
  int *procL   = mpi_decomp->procL;
  int *procR   = mpi_decomp->procR;
  int *start   = mpi_decomp->start;
  int new_coords[NDIM];

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   1. Get rank & size
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  mpi_decomp->rank = rank;
  mpi_decomp->size = size;

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   2. Obtain number of processor along each dimension.
      Use maximally squared decomp.
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  nprocs[0] = (int)sqrt(size);
  nprocs[1] = size/nprocs[0];
  if (nprocs[0]*nprocs[1] != size){
    if (rank == 0) printf ("! Cannot decompose\n");
    MPI_Finalize();
    exit(1);
  }
  if (rank == 0){
    printf ("Decomposition achieved with %d X %d procs\n",nprocs[0],nprocs[1]);
  }

  periods[0] = 0;
  periods[1] = 0;

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   3. Create Cartesian topology
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, NDIM, nprocs, periods,
                                        0, &MPI_COMM_CART);
  MPI_Cart_get(MPI_COMM_CART, NDIM, nprocs, periods, coords);

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   4. Fill structure members
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  gsize[0] = NX_GLOB;
  gsize[1] = NY_GLOB;
  lsize[0] = NX_GLOB/nprocs[0];
  lsize[1] = NY_GLOB/nprocs[1];
  start[0] = coords[0]*lsize[0];
  start[1] = coords[1]*lsize[1];

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   5. Determine ranks of neighbour processors
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  for (dim = 0; dim < NDIM; dim++) {
    for (i = 0; i < NDIM; i++) new_coords[i] = coords[i];

    new_coords[dim] = coords[dim] + 1;
    if (new_coords[dim] < nprocs[dim]) {
      MPI_Cart_rank ( MPI_COMM_CART, new_coords, &(procR[dim]) );
    } else {
      procR[dim] = MPI_PROC_NULL;
    }

    new_coords[dim] = coords[dim] - 1;
    if (new_coords[dim] >= 0) {
     MPI_Cart_rank ( MPI_COMM_CART, new_coords, &(procL[dim]) );
    } else {
      procL[dim] = MPI_PROC_NULL;
    }
  }

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   6. Print processor information.
      (Use MPI_Bcast() to print in sequence)
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  int proc, go;
  for (proc = 0; proc < size; proc++){
    go = proc;
    MPI_Bcast(&go, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == go) {
      printf ("[Rank %d]\n",rank);
      printf ("  coords = [%d, %d], lsize = [%d, %d]\n",
                 coords[0], coords[1], lsize[0], lsize[1]);
      for (dim = 0; dim < NDIM; dim++){
        printf ("  (procL, procR)[%d] = %d, %d\n", dim, procL[dim], procR[dim]);
      }
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  return;
}
#endif

/* ********************************************************************* */
void BoundaryConditions(double **phi, double *x, double *y,
                        int nx, int ny, MPI_Decomp *mpi_decomp)
/*
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i,j;
  int ibeg   = NGHOST;
  int iend   = ibeg + nx - 1;

  int jbeg   = NGHOST;
  int jend   = jbeg + ny - 1;

  int *procL = mpi_decomp->procL;
  int *procR = mpi_decomp->procR;
#ifdef PARALLEL
  int rank = mpi_decomp->rank;
  int size = mpi_decomp->size;
  double send_buf[NX_GLOB + 2*NGHOST];
  double recv_buf[NX_GLOB + 2*NGHOST];

/*  Used for testing
    for (j = 0; j <= jend+1; j++){
    for (i = 0; i <= iend+1; i++){
      phi[j][i] = -1;
    }}

    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
      phi[j][i] = rank;
    }}
*/

  #pragma acc enter data create(send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])

  // Left buffer
  i = ibeg;

  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) send_buf[j] = phi[j][i];
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, jend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procL[0], 0,
                recv_buf, jend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procL[0], 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) phi[j][i-1] = recv_buf[j];

  // Right buffer
  i = iend;
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) send_buf[j] = phi[j][i];
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, jend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[0], 0,
                recv_buf, jend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[0], 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) phi[j][i+1] = recv_buf[j];


  // Bottom buffer
  j = jbeg;
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) send_buf[i] = phi[j][i];
  // #pragma acc update self(send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procL[1], 0,
                  recv_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procL[1], 0,
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j-1][i] = recv_buf[i];

  // Top buffer
  j = jend;
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) send_buf[i] = phi[j][i];
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0,
                recv_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j+1][i] = recv_buf[i];

  #pragma acc exit data copyout(send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])

#endif

/* -- Left -- */

  if (procL[0] < 0){
    i = ibeg-1;
    #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], y[:NY_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) phi[j][i] = 1.0-y[j];
  }

/* -- Right -- */

  if (procR[0] < 0){
    i = iend+1;
    #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], y[:NY_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) phi[j][i] = y[j]*y[j];
  }

/* -- Bottom -- */

  if (procL[1] < 0){
    j = jbeg-1;
    #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], x[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j][i] = 1.0-x[i];
  }

/* -- Top -- */

  if (procR[1] < 0){
    j = jend+1;
    #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], x[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j][i] = x[i];
  }

  return;

#ifdef PARALLEL
// Print
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  int go, proc;
  for (proc = 0; proc < size; proc++){
    go = proc;
    MPI_Bcast(&go, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == go) {
      printf ("Boundary [Rank %d]\n",rank);
      for (j = jend+1; j >= 0; j--){
        for (i = 0; i <= iend+1; i++){
          printf ("%6.2f  ", phi[j][i]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
      }
    }
  }

MPI_Finalize();
exit(0);
#endif
}

/* ********************************************************************* */
void WriteSolution (double **phi, int nx, int ny, MPI_Decomp *md)
/*
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i,j;
  int ibeg   = NGHOST;
  int iend   = ibeg + nx - 1;

  int jbeg   = NGHOST;
  int jend   = jbeg + ny - 1;

  static int nfile = 0;
  char fname[32];

  sprintf (fname,"laplace2D_MPIACC.txt",nfile);

/*
for (j = jbeg-1; j <= jend+1; j++) for (i = ibeg-1; i <= iend+1; i++) {
  phi[j][i] = -1;
}
for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) {
  phi[j][i] = md->rank;
}
*/
#ifdef PARALLEL
  MPI_File fh;
  MPI_Datatype type_local, type_domain;
  int amode = MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY;
  int gsize[2], lsize[2], start[2];

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   1. Create a local array type without the ghost zones
      This datatype will be passed to MPI_File_write()
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  gsize[0] = md->lsize[0] + 2*NGHOST;
  gsize[1] = md->lsize[1] + 2*NGHOST;

  lsize[0] = md->lsize[0];
  lsize[1] = md->lsize[1];

  start[0] = NGHOST;
  start[1] = NGHOST;

  MPI_Type_create_subarray (NDIM, gsize, lsize, start,
                            MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE, &type_local);
  MPI_Type_commit (&type_local);

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   2. Create the subarry in the global domain.
      This datatype is used to set the file view.
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  gsize[0] = NX_GLOB;
  gsize[1] = NY_GLOB;

  lsize[0] = md->lsize[0];
  lsize[1] = md->lsize[1];

  start[0] = lsize[0]*md->coords[0];  // equal to md->start[0]
  start[1] = lsize[1]*md->coords[1];  // equal to md->start[1]

  MPI_Type_create_subarray (NDIM, gsize, lsize, start,
                            MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE, &type_domain);
  MPI_Type_commit (&type_domain);

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   3. Write to disk
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  MPI_File_delete(fname, MPI_INFO_NULL);
  MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_CART, fname, amode, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
  MPI_File_set_view(fh, 0, MPI_DOUBLE, type_domain, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
  MPI_File_write_all(fh, phi[0], 1, type_local, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_File_close(&fh);
  MPI_Type_free (&type_local);
  MPI_Type_free (&type_domain);
#else
  FILE *fp;
  printf ("> Writing %s\n",fname);
  fp = fopen(fname, "wb");

  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
    fwrite (phi[j] + ibeg, sizeof(double), nx, fp);
  }

  fclose(fp);
#endif

  nfile++;
}

/* ********************************************************************* */
double **Allocate_2DdblArray(int nx, int ny)
/*
 * Allocate memory for a double precision array with
 * nx rows and ny columns
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i,j;
  double **buf;

  buf    = (double **)malloc (nx*sizeof(double *));
  buf[0] = (double *) malloc (nx*ny*sizeof(double));
  for (j = 1; j < nx; j++) buf[j] = buf[j-1] + ny;

  return buf;
}
/* ********************************************************************* */
int **Allocate_2DintArray(int nx, int ny)
/*
 * Allocate memory for an integer-type array with
 * nx rows and ny columns
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i,j;
  int **buf;

  buf    = (int **)malloc (nx*sizeof(int *));
  buf[0] = (int *) malloc (nx*ny*sizeof(int));
  for (j = 1; j < nx; j++) buf[j] = buf[j-1] + ny;

  return buf;
}


/* ********************************************************************* */
void Show_2DdblArray(double **A, int nx, int ny, const char *string)
/*
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i, j;

  printf ("%s\n",string);
  printf ("------------------------------\n");
  for (i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
      printf ("%8.2f  ", A[i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }
  printf ("------------------------------\n");
}
/* ********************************************************************* */
void Show_2DintArray(int **A, int nx, int ny, const char *string)
/*
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i, j;

  printf ("%s\n",string);
  for (j = 0; j < ny; j++) printf ("-----");
  printf ("\n");

  for (i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
      printf ("%03d  ", A[i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }

  for (j = 0; j < ny; j++) printf ("-----");
  printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you up the code so it's complete?  I'd like to try and reproduce the issue so I can better understand what's going on.  Reduction variables like err are treated a bit differently in that by default they are copied back to the host, but I'd think it would update the device copy as well since you managing it in data directives.  So it might be a compiler issue but without a full reproducer it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: @MatColgrove Thank you. I edited the question, now there's all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating the example.  There's a few issues here.

First, for "err" and "err_glob".  At the beginning of the loop, you set "err=0" on the host but don't update it on the device.  Then after the MPI_AllReduce call, you set "err=err_glob", again on the host, so need to update "err_glob".

The second issue is that the code is getting partially present errors for "y" when run with multiple ranks.  The problem being you're using the global size not the local size for "x" and "y" so when you copy "y" it overlaps with "x" due to the offsets.  I fixed this by copying "xg" and "yg" to the device instead.

As for performance relative to the CPU, the main problem here is that the size is small so the code severly under utilizes the GPU.  I increased the GLOB sizes to 4096 and see better relative performance, though the code converges much faster.

I also took the liberty of adding some boiler plate code that I use for rank to device assignment so the code can take advantage of multiple GPUs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PARALLEL
#define NX_GLOB     128   /* Global number of interior points */
#define NY_GLOB     128  /* Global number of interior points */
#define NGHOST   1
#define NDIM     2

#ifdef PARALLEL
  #include <mpi.h>
  MPI_Comm MPI_COMM_CART;
#endif

#ifdef _OPENACC
  #include <openacc.h>
#endif

typedef struct MPI_Decomp_{
  int nprocs[NDIM];     /*  Number of processors in each dimension */
  int periods[NDIM];    /*  Periodicity flag in each dimension     */
  int coords[NDIM];     /*  Cartesian coordinate in the MPI topology */
  int gsize[NDIM];      /*  Global domain size (no ghosts)  */
  int lsize[NDIM];      /*  Local domain size (no ghosts)   */
  int start[NDIM];      /*  Local start index in each dimension           */
  int procL[NDIM];      /*  Rank of left-lying  process in each direction */
  int procR[NDIM];      /*  Rank of right-lying process in each direction */
  int rank;             /*  Local process rank */
  int size;             /*  Communicator size  */
} MPI_Decomp;



void BoundaryConditions(double **, double *, double *, int, int, MPI_Decomp *);
void DomainDecomposition(MPI_Decomp *);
void WriteSolution (double **, int, int, MPI_Decomp *);
double **Allocate_2DdblArray(int, int);
int    **Allocate_2DintArray(int, int);
void   Show_2DdblArray(double **, int, int, const char *);
void   Show_2DintArray(int **, int, int, const char *);

int nx_tot, ny_tot;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int    nx, i, ibeg, iend;
  int    ny, j, jbeg, jend;
  int    k, rank=0, size=1;
  int xsize,ysize;
  double xbeg = 0.0, xend = 1.0;
  double ybeg = 0.0, yend = 1.0;
  double dx = (xend - xbeg)/(NX_GLOB + 1);
  double dy = (yend - ybeg)/(NY_GLOB + 1);
  double *xg, *yg, *x, *y, **phi, **phi0;
  double err, tol;
  MPI_Decomp  mpi_decomp;
  double err_glob;
  int procL[NDIM] = {-1,-1};
  int procR[NDIM] = {-1,-1};

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   0. Initialize the MPI execution environment
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

#ifdef PARALLEL
  MPI_Datatype row_type, col_type;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  DomainDecomposition(&mpi_decomp);
  nx = mpi_decomp.lsize[0];
  ny = mpi_decomp.lsize[1];
#else
  mpi_decomp.gsize[0] = mpi_decomp.lsize[0] = nx = NX_GLOB;
  mpi_decomp.gsize[1] = mpi_decomp.lsize[1] = ny = NY_GLOB;
  mpi_decomp.procL[0] = mpi_decomp.procL[1] = -1;
  mpi_decomp.procR[0] = mpi_decomp.procR[1] = -1;
#endif

#ifdef _OPENACC
/* -------------------------------------------------------
   0. Set the device for each rank
   ------------------------------------------------------- */
  int device_type, num_devices;
  int gpuId;
  MPI_Comm shmcomm;
  int local_rank;

// Get the local rank number
  MPI_Comm_split_type(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED, 0,
                      MPI_INFO_NULL, &shmcomm);
  MPI_Comm_rank(shmcomm, &local_rank);

// Device num = local rank mod number of devices on the node
  device_type = acc_get_device_type();
  num_devices = acc_get_num_devices(device_type);
  gpuId = local_rank % num_devices;
  acc_set_device_num(gpuId, device_type);
  acc_init(device_type);
#endif

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   1. Set local grid indices
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  ibeg   = NGHOST;
  iend   = ibeg + nx - 1;
  nx     = iend - ibeg + 1;
  nx_tot = nx + 2*NGHOST;

  jbeg   = NGHOST;
  jend   = jbeg + ny - 1;
  ny     = jend - jbeg + 1;
  ny_tot = ny + 2*NGHOST;

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   2. Generate global and local grids
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  xg = (double *) malloc ( (NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST)*sizeof(double));
  yg = (double *) malloc ( (NY_GLOB+2*NGHOST)*sizeof(double));
  for (i = 0; i < (NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST); i++) xg[i] = xbeg + (i-ibeg+1)*dx;
  for (j = 0; j < (NY_GLOB+2*NGHOST); j++) yg[j] = ybeg + (j-jbeg+1)*dy;
#pragma acc enter data copyin(xg[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST],yg[:NY_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  #ifdef PARALLEL
  x = xg + mpi_decomp.start[0];
  y = yg + mpi_decomp.start[1];
  #else
  x = xg;
  y = yg;
  #endif

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   3. Allocate memory on local processor and
      assign initial conditions.
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  phi  = Allocate_2DdblArray(ny_tot, nx_tot);
  phi0 = Allocate_2DdblArray(ny_tot, nx_tot);

  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
    phi0[j][i] = 0.0;
  }}

#ifdef PARALLEL
  MPI_Type_contiguous (nx_tot, MPI_DOUBLE, &row_type);
  MPI_Type_vector     (ny_tot, 1, nx_tot, MPI_DOUBLE, &col_type);
  MPI_Type_commit (&row_type);
  MPI_Type_commit (&col_type);
#endif

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   4. Main iteration cycle
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  tol = 1.e-5;
  err = 1.0;
  k   = 0;

  //#pragma acc enter data copyin(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], phi0[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], x[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], y[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  #pragma acc enter data copyin(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], phi0[:ny_tot][:nx_tot],err,err_glob)
 while  (err > tol){

  /* -- 4a. Set boundary conditions first -- */

    BoundaryConditions(phi0, x, y, nx, ny, &mpi_decomp);

  /* -- 4b. Jacobi's method and residual (interior points) -- */

    err = 0.0;
#pragma acc update device(err)

    #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) reduction(+:err) present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], phi0[:ny_tot][:nx_tot])
    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
      phi[j][i] = 0.25*(  phi0[j][i-1] + phi0[j][i+1]
                        + phi0[j-1][i] + phi0[j+1][i] );

      err += dx*dy*fabs(phi[j][i] - phi0[j][i]);
    }}


    #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], phi0[:ny_tot][:nx_tot])
    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
      phi0[j][i] = phi[j][i];
    }}

    #ifdef PARALLEL
    // double err_glob;
    #pragma acc host_data use_device(err, err_glob)
    {
    MPI_Allreduce (&err, &err_glob, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    #pragma acc update host(err_glob)
    err = err_glob;
    #endif

    if (rank == 0){
      printf ("k = %d; err = %8.3e\n",k, err);
    }
    k++;
  }
  #pragma acc exit data copyout(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], phi0[:ny_tot][:nx_tot],err,err_glob)

  WriteSolution (phi, nx, ny, &mpi_decomp);

  #ifdef PARALLEL
  MPI_Finalize();
  #endif
  return 0;
}

#ifdef PARALLEL
/* ********************************************************************* */
void DomainDecomposition(MPI_Decomp *mpi_decomp)
/*
 *
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int dim, i;
  int rank, size;
  int *coords  = mpi_decomp->coords;
  int *gsize   = mpi_decomp->gsize;
  int *lsize   = mpi_decomp->lsize;
  int *nprocs  = mpi_decomp->nprocs;
  int *periods = mpi_decomp->periods;
  int *procL   = mpi_decomp->procL;
  int *procR   = mpi_decomp->procR;
  int *start   = mpi_decomp->start;
  int new_coords[NDIM];

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   1. Get rank & size
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  mpi_decomp->rank = rank;
  mpi_decomp->size = size;

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   2. Obtain number of processor along each dimension.
      Use maximally squared decomp.
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  nprocs[0] = (int)sqrt(size);
  nprocs[1] = size/nprocs[0];
  if (nprocs[0]*nprocs[1] != size){
    if (rank == 0) printf ("! Cannot decompose\n");
    MPI_Finalize();
    exit(1);
  }
  if (rank == 0){
    printf ("Decomposition achieved with %d X %d procs\n",nprocs[0],nprocs[1]);
  }

  periods[0] = 0;
  periods[1] = 0;

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   3. Create Cartesian topology
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, NDIM, nprocs, periods,
                                        0, &MPI_COMM_CART);
  MPI_Cart_get(MPI_COMM_CART, NDIM, nprocs, periods, coords);

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   4. Fill structure members
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  gsize[0] = NX_GLOB;
  gsize[1] = NY_GLOB;
  lsize[0] = NX_GLOB/nprocs[0];
  lsize[1] = NY_GLOB/nprocs[1];
  start[0] = coords[0]*lsize[0];
  start[1] = coords[1]*lsize[1];

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   5. Determine ranks of neighbour processors
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  for (dim = 0; dim < NDIM; dim++) {
    for (i = 0; i < NDIM; i++) new_coords[i] = coords[i];

    new_coords[dim] = coords[dim] + 1;
    if (new_coords[dim] < nprocs[dim]) {
      MPI_Cart_rank ( MPI_COMM_CART, new_coords, &(procR[dim]) );
    } else {
      procR[dim] = MPI_PROC_NULL;
    }

    new_coords[dim] = coords[dim] - 1;
    if (new_coords[dim] >= 0) {
     MPI_Cart_rank ( MPI_COMM_CART, new_coords, &(procL[dim]) );
    } else {
      procL[dim] = MPI_PROC_NULL;
    }
  }

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   6. Print processor information.
      (Use MPI_Bcast() to print in sequence)
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  int proc, go;
  for (proc = 0; proc < size; proc++){
    go = proc;
    MPI_Bcast(&go, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == go) {
      printf ("[Rank %d]\n",rank);
      printf ("  coords = [%d, %d], lsize = [%d, %d]\n",
                 coords[0], coords[1], lsize[0], lsize[1]);
      for (dim = 0; dim < NDIM; dim++){
        printf ("  (procL, procR)[%d] = %d, %d\n", dim, procL[dim], procR[dim]);
      }
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  return;
}
#endif

/* ********************************************************************* */
void BoundaryConditions(double **phi, double *x, double *y,
                        int nx, int ny, MPI_Decomp *mpi_decomp)
/*
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i,j;
  int ibeg   = NGHOST;
  int iend   = ibeg + nx - 1;

  int jbeg   = NGHOST;
  int jend   = jbeg + ny - 1;

  int *procL = mpi_decomp->procL;
  int *procR = mpi_decomp->procR;
#ifdef PARALLEL
  int rank = mpi_decomp->rank;
  int size = mpi_decomp->size;
  double send_buf[NX_GLOB + 2*NGHOST];
  double recv_buf[NX_GLOB + 2*NGHOST];

/*  Used for testing
    for (j = 0; j <= jend+1; j++){
    for (i = 0; i <= iend+1; i++){
      phi[j][i] = -1;
    }}

    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
      phi[j][i] = rank;
    }}
*/

  #pragma acc enter data create(send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])

  // Left buffer
  i = ibeg;

  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) send_buf[j] = phi[j][i];
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, jend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procL[0], 0,
                recv_buf, jend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procL[0], 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) phi[j][i-1] = recv_buf[j];

  // Right buffer
  i = iend;
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) send_buf[j] = phi[j][i];
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, jend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[0], 0,
                recv_buf, jend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[0], 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) phi[j][i+1] = recv_buf[j];


  // Bottom buffer
  j = jbeg;
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) send_buf[i] = phi[j][i];
  // #pragma acc update self(send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procL[1], 0,
                  recv_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procL[1], 0,
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j-1][i] = recv_buf[i];

  // Top buffer
  j = jend;
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) send_buf[i] = phi[j][i];
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0,
                recv_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j+1][i] = recv_buf[i];

  #pragma acc exit data copyout(send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])

#endif

/* -- Left -- */

  if (procL[0] < 0){
    i = ibeg-1;
    #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], y)
    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) phi[j][i] = 1.0-y[j];
  }

/* -- Right -- */

  if (procR[0] < 0){
    i = iend+1;
    #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], y)
    for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) phi[j][i] = y[j]*y[j];
  }

/* -- Bottom -- */

  if (procL[1] < 0){
    j = jbeg-1;
    #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], x)
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j][i] = 1.0-x[i];
  }

/* -- Top -- */

  if (procR[1] < 0){
    j = jend+1;
    #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], x)
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j][i] = x[i];
  }

  return;

#ifdef PARALLEL
// Print
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  int go, proc;
  for (proc = 0; proc < size; proc++){
    go = proc;
    MPI_Bcast(&go, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == go) {
      printf ("Boundary [Rank %d]\n",rank);
      for (j = jend+1; j >= 0; j--){
        for (i = 0; i <= iend+1; i++){
          printf ("%6.2f  ", phi[j][i]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
      }
    }
  }

MPI_Finalize();
exit(0);
#endif
}

/* ********************************************************************* */
void WriteSolution (double **phi, int nx, int ny, MPI_Decomp *md)
/*
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i,j;
  int ibeg   = NGHOST;
  int iend   = ibeg + nx - 1;

  int jbeg   = NGHOST;
  int jend   = jbeg + ny - 1;

  static int nfile = 0;
  char fname[32];

  sprintf (fname,"laplace2D_MPIACC.txt",nfile);

/*
for (j = jbeg-1; j <= jend+1; j++) for (i = ibeg-1; i <= iend+1; i++) {
  phi[j][i] = -1;
}
for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++) for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) {
  phi[j][i] = md->rank;
}
*/
#ifdef PARALLEL
  MPI_File fh;
  MPI_Datatype type_local, type_domain;
  int amode = MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY;
  int gsize[2], lsize[2], start[2];

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   1. Create a local array type without the ghost zones
      This datatype will be passed to MPI_File_write()
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  gsize[0] = md->lsize[0] + 2*NGHOST;
  gsize[1] = md->lsize[1] + 2*NGHOST;

  lsize[0] = md->lsize[0];
  lsize[1] = md->lsize[1];

  start[0] = NGHOST;
  start[1] = NGHOST;

  MPI_Type_create_subarray (NDIM, gsize, lsize, start,
                            MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE, &type_local);
  MPI_Type_commit (&type_local);

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   2. Create the subarry in the global domain.
      This datatype is used to set the file view.
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  gsize[0] = NX_GLOB;
  gsize[1] = NY_GLOB;

  lsize[0] = md->lsize[0];
  lsize[1] = md->lsize[1];

  start[0] = lsize[0]*md->coords[0];  // equal to md->start[0]
  start[1] = lsize[1]*md->coords[1];  // equal to md->start[1]

  MPI_Type_create_subarray (NDIM, gsize, lsize, start,
                            MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE, &type_domain);
  MPI_Type_commit (&type_domain);

/* --------------------------------------------------------
   3. Write to disk
   -------------------------------------------------------- */

  MPI_File_delete(fname, MPI_INFO_NULL);
  MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_CART, fname, amode, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
  MPI_File_set_view(fh, 0, MPI_DOUBLE, type_domain, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
  MPI_File_write_all(fh, phi[0], 1, type_local, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_File_close(&fh);
  MPI_Type_free (&type_local);
  MPI_Type_free (&type_domain);
#else
  FILE *fp;
  printf ("> Writing %s\n",fname);
  fp = fopen(fname, "wb");

  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
    fwrite (phi[j] + ibeg, sizeof(double), nx, fp);
  }

  fclose(fp);
#endif

  nfile++;
}

/* ********************************************************************* */
double **Allocate_2DdblArray(int nx, int ny)
/*
 * Allocate memory for a double precision array with
 * nx rows and ny columns
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i,j;
  double **buf;

  buf    = (double **)malloc (nx*sizeof(double *));
  buf[0] = (double *) malloc (nx*ny*sizeof(double));
  for (j = 1; j < nx; j++) buf[j] = buf[j-1] + ny;

  return buf;
}
/* ********************************************************************* */
int **Allocate_2DintArray(int nx, int ny)
/*
 * Allocate memory for an integer-type array with
 * nx rows and ny columns
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i,j;
  int **buf;

  buf    = (int **)malloc (nx*sizeof(int *));
  buf[0] = (int *) malloc (nx*ny*sizeof(int));
  for (j = 1; j < nx; j++) buf[j] = buf[j-1] + ny;

  return buf;
}


/* ********************************************************************* */
void Show_2DdblArray(double **A, int nx, int ny, const char *string)
/*
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i, j;

  printf ("%s\n",string);
  printf ("------------------------------\n");
  for (i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
      printf ("%8.2f  ", A[i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }
  printf ("------------------------------\n");
}
/* ********************************************************************* */
void Show_2DintArray(int **A, int nx, int ny, const char *string)
/*
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int i, j;

  printf ("%s\n",string);
  for (j = 0; j < ny; j++) printf ("-----");
  printf ("\n");

  for (i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
      printf ("%03d  ", A[i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }

  for (j = 0; j < ny; j++) printf ("-----");
  printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mat, this was really helpful and clear. I don't get, though, the question of x and y. Keeping my original version with the global size I don't get any error and the results are ok. In the boundary function I pass the whole x and y arrays (that are then used in the loops), not xg and yg.

Comment: For the enter data directive, you're using "y[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST]", which is the same size as "yg".  Though it looks like "y" is an offset (depending on the rank count) into "yg" so wouldn't have the same size.  The code works with one rank, but I'm seeing a partially present error with "y" when using 2 ranks, presumably because the incorrect size is causing the memory to overlap with another device variable.

Comment: Oh I see, you're right. But then why copy xg and yg should fix this? to the Boundary function are passe x and y not xg and yg, how the compiler could know that it can use the latter two instead?

Comment: The correlation between the host and device copies of a variable is done via addresses, not variable name.  Since x and y point into xg and yg, when the present table lookup is made, the runtime can tell this and then pass into the device kernel a device pointer the appropriate offset into the device copy of xg or yg.